# How to write a function to get if a family is balanced on not?

Tags: python, recursion

The goal is to find out if a family is balanced or not. For example we have the following 2 arrays:

```
kids= {
"Adam": ["Matjaž", "Cilka", "Daniel"],
"Aleksander": [],
"Alenka": [],
"Barbara": [],
"Cilka": [],
"Daniel": ["Elizabeta", "Hans"],
"Erik": [],
"Elizabeta": ["Ludvik", "Jurij", "Barbara"],
"Franc": [],
"Herman": ["Margareta"],
"Hans": ["Herman", "Erik"],
"Jožef": ["Alenka", "Aleksander", "Petra"],
"Jurij": ["Franc", "Jožef"],
"Ludvik": [],
"Margareta": [],
"Matjaž": ["Viljem"],
"Petra": [],
"Tadeja": [],
"Viljem": ["Tadeja"],
}
```

The kids array tells you who's family member is who's kid. (It's a global array)

```
money= {
        "Adam": 42,
        "Aleksander": 3,
        "Alenka": 3,
        "Barbara": 37,
        "Cilka": 242,
        "Daniel": 4,
        "Erik": 32,
        "Elizabeta": 8,
        "Franc": 16,
        "Herman": 12,
        "Hans": 55,
        "Jožef": 7,
        "Jurij": 5,
        "Ludvik": 37,
        "Margareta": 20,
        "Matjaž": 142,
        "Petra": 3,
        "Tadeja": 45,
        "Viljem": 55
    }
```

The money array tells you how much money does every person have.

We have this function:

```
def balanced(person, money):
   #should return true if the family is balanced or not, if not returns false
```

For example: we call the function:

```
balanced("Adam", money)
```

It should return true because Adam has 3 kids and those kids have kids. And if we add their amount of money we get the same value.

1. Matjaž (142)

   - Viljem (55)

     - Tadeja (45)
       SUM = 242
2. Cilka (242)

   - no kids 
     SUM = 242
3. Daniel (4)

   - Elizabeta (8)

     - Ludvik (37)
     - Jurij (5)

       - Franc (16)
       - Jožef (7)

         - Alenka (3)
         - Aleksander (3)
         - Petra (3)
     - Barbara (37)
   - Hans (55)

     - Herman (12)

       - Margareta (20)
     - Erik (32)
       SUM = 242

All 3 kids return total money value of 242 and because all 3 do that it returns TRUE as a balanced family.

I have already written a function to calculate the money of a family member and their descendants:

```
def amount_of_money(person, money):
    amount = 0
    for kid in kids[person]:
        amount += amount_of_money(kid, money)
    return amount + money[person]
```

Now how would I write the function `balanced` for it to return true if this happens?

Comment: "And if we add their amount of money we get the same value." Which money values are you adding? And who's are the same value? When you describe the problem more specifically, the code will almost write itself.

Comment: If I call the function with the persons name "Adam", it goes and checks the kids array and sees that Adam has 3 kids. Now the function balanced should go and add the amount of money for each of these 3 kids and his/hers descendants. If the amount of money for all of the 3 is the same it should return true.  Else it returns false

Comment: Okay, now translate that into code. Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Is `money` not global like `kids`? Feels inconsistent.

Comment: Sorry I have misread your question and edited my answer.

Comment: @NejcŽun If an answer worked for you mark it as accepted please. Thanks

Comment: @Ivan86 I've been testing around and the most optimal solution has been marked below. Thanks for all the help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we want to first generate a `list` of all the kid's money (and there kids) using the function you already have. We can do this with a `comprehension`.

Then, we can use `all()` on a `generator` to check if all of the kid's money is the same (i.e. it is *balanced*).

All in all, the function comes down to `2` lines:

```
def balanced(person, money):
    kidsMoney = [amount_of_money(k, money) for k in kids[person]]
    return all(m == kidsMoney[0] for m in kidsMoney)
```

and it does work:

```
>>> balanced("Adam", money)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the set of family amounts has at most one?

```
def balanced(person, money):
    return len({amount_of_money(kid, money) for kid in kids[person]}) <= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already done most of the heavy lifting in `amount_of_money()`.  For `balanced()`, you could use:

```
def balanced(person, money):
    kid_amounts = [amount_of_money(kid, money) for kid in kids[person]]
    return len(set(kid_amounts)) <= 1
```

We use a list comprehension to grab all the monies possessed by each kid. Then we create a set from those amounts and see how long it is. If all the amounts are the same, the length of the set will be 1 (because sets are guaranteed to only have unique values). And assuming that someone with no kids would be considered "balanced", we also will accept an empty set (or list) of amounts. So, `<= 1` works when the amounts are all the same, or there are no amounts.